"Open in terminal" hangs in Visual Studio 2022
I'm using latest version of Visual Studio 2022 and when I right click on a solution and click "Open in Terminal" the terminal panel opens but nothing happens, it just stays blank with a blinking cursor but never reaches the command prompt, like this:

Any idea about how I can diagnose or fix this?

Maybe try a Visual Studio repair?

In my Case this issue solved by following these steps:
1- Go to Tools > Options > Environment > Terminal
2- Click on Developer Powershell(Default)
3- In the arguments text box start by remove the arguments one by one and try to open the terminal every time if not working remove all arguments and try again.
Or you can try to run vs2022 as administrator


Removing ALL arguments worked, if I leave even just one it hangs. Good enough for now I guess, although I don't really know what I'm missing without all those args...
